# Поместить код в функцию

Tags: python, функции, slider, matplotlib

Есть код. Нужно его оформить в виде одной функции, что бы вызывать его при необходимости. Проблема в том, что когда код помещаю в функцию, и пытаюсь ее выполнить, выдается ошибка: NameError: name 'slider_sigma' is not defined

```
import numpy
import pylab
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def gauss(sigma, mu, x):
    # '''Отображаемая фукнция'''
    return (1.0 / (sigma * numpy.sqrt(2.0 * numpy.pi)) *
            numpy.exp(-((x - mu) ** 2) / (2 * sigma * sigma)))


def updateGraph():
    # '''!!! Функция для обновления графика'''
    global slider_sigma
    global slider_mu
    global graph_axes

    sigma = slider_sigma.val
    mu = slider_mu.val
    x = numpy.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.01)
    y = gauss(sigma, mu, x)

    graph_axes.clear()
    graph_axes.plot(x, y)
    pylab.draw()

def onChangeValue(value):
    # '''!!! Обработчик события изменения значений слайдеров'''
    updateGraph()

# Создадим окно с графиком

fig, graph_axes = pylab.subplots()
graph_axes.grid()

# Оставим снизу от графика место для виджетов
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.95, top=0.95, bottom=0.4)

# Создание слайдера для задания sigma
axes_slider_sigma = pylab.axes([0.05, 0.25, 0.85, 0.04])
slider_sigma = Slider(axes_slider_sigma,
                      label='σ',
                      valmin=0.1,
                      valmax=1.0,
                      valinit=0.5,
                      valfmt='%1.2f')

# !!! Подпишемся на событие при изменении значения слайдера.
slider_sigma.on_changed(onChangeValue)

# Создание слайдера для задания mu
axes_slider_mu = pylab.axes([0.05, 0.17, 0.85, 0.04])
slider_mu = Slider(axes_slider_mu,
                   label='μ',
                   valmin=-4.0,
                   valmax=4.0,
                   valinit=0.0,
                   valfmt='%1.2f')

# !!! Подпишемся на событие при изменении значения слайдера.
slider_mu.on_changed(onChangeValue)

updateGraph()
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так, чтобы лишнее в функцию не передавать и без глобальных переменных:

```
def updateGraph(sigma, mu, graph_axes):
    # '''!!! Функция для обновления графика'''

    x = numpy.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.01)
    y = gauss(sigma, mu, x)

    graph_axes.clear()
    graph_axes.plot(x, y)
    pylab.draw()

# здесь остальной код с созданием слайдеров

updateGraph(slider_sigma.val, slider_mu.val, graph_axes)
```

Может и ошибка исчезнет. Либо станет понятно, что ошибка не там.

Я, кстати, попробовал в Google Colaboratory ваш код - у меня всё работает. И мой вариант кода тоже работает.

[image: картинка]

Comment: Как я понимаю, если убрать глобальные переменные то как будут создаваться слайдеры, которые ниже

Comment: @VasyaHmm В Питоне всё не так, как в других языках зачастую. Вот и инструкция global не создаёт ничего, она лишь говорит функции, где искать переменную по названию - не в локальных переменных функции, а в глобальных переменных всего скрипта. Слайдеры у вас создаёт основная часть скрипта, а не функция, которую вы по факту всё-равно вызываете позже чем основной код.

Comment: @VasyaHmm updateGraph конечно надо вызывать там же, где вы его вызываете, я просто код сократил только до значимой части